# inserting new recording and updating the foreignkey

Tags: t-sql

I have tables like this

MainTable

```
 Id FolderName   Description      UserId
 1   Folder1     Description1       1
 2   Folder1     Description2       1
 3   Folder1     Desctiption3       1
 4   Folder2     Description1       2
 5   Folder2     Description2       2
```

ChildTable

```
 Id  FolderId     Title     UserId   imageName
 1      1          AA         1        AAA
 2      1          BB         1        BBB
 3      2          CC         1        CCC
 4      3          DD         1        DDD
 5      4          EE         2        EEE
```

I want to select all records in MainTable and ChildTable For userId=1 and insert them again into MainTable/ChildTable but with UserId=5, so the FolderId for the new records should be updated, so the result should be like this:

```
Id FolderName   Description      UserId
 1   Folder1     Description1       1
 2   Folder1     Description2       1
 3   Folder1     Desctiption3       1
 4   Folder2     Description1       2
 5   Folder2     Description2       2
 6   Folder1     Description1       5
 7   Folder1     Description2       5
 8   Folder1     Desctiption3       5


 Id  FolderId     Title     UserId   imageName
 1      1          AA         1        AAA
 2      1          BB         1        BBB
 3      2          CC         1        CCC
 4      3          DD         1        DDD
 5      4          EE         2        EEE
 6      6          AA         5        AAA
 7      6          BB         5        BBB
 8      7          CC         5        CCC
 9      8          DD         5        DDD
```

how can i do that?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t table (OldFolderId int, NewFolderId int);

MERGE MainTable AS m
USING (SELECT Id, FolderName, Description
       FROM MainTable AS m
       WHERE UserId = 1) AS src
ON 1=2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (FolderName, Description, UserId)
  VALUES (src.FolderName, src.Description, 5)
OUTPUT src.Id AS OldFolderId, inserted.Id AS NewFolderId
INTO @t;

INSERT ChildTable (FolderId, Title, UserId, imageName)

SELECT t.NewFolderId, Title, 5, imageName
FROM ChildTable c
INNER JOIN @t t ON t.OldFolderId = c.FolderID
WHERE c.UserId = 1;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be81d/1/1)